# Skip metadata for large binary fields in fastparquet

Tags: python, dask, parquet, fastparquet

If a dataset has a column with large binary data (e.g. an image or a sound-wave data) then computing min/max statistics for that column becomes costly both in compute and storage requirements, despite being completely useless (querying these values by range obviously makes no sense).

This causes large, highly-partitioned, parquet datasets to have metadata that explodes in size. Is there a way to tell fastparquet to **not** compute statistics for some columns or does the Parquet format mandate these statistics exist for **every** column?

Comment: Note: with the latest version of pyarrow (>= 0.14) this is possible by specifying the `write_statistics` keyword. See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implemented in a [stale PR](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/pull/259/files?file-filters%5B%5D=.py#diff-81ae5d6b978939ec10070fd71c51bf7fR735) which could either be merged sometime (it breaks compatibility with py2), or the relevant parts could be extracted. The PR provides a `stats=` arg to the writer, which can be used to pick which columns have their max/min computed, or all/none for True/False.